# How do generic types get inferred in Java?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, type-inference

The `Function.identity()` returns  a function, `Function<T, T>` that always returns its input argument(i.e. *identity function*).

But being a static method, how does it know which concrete argument to return in place of type parameter `T` when it doesn't even take any inputs?

Illustration of my thought process:

```
Map idToPerson = people.collect( Collectors.toMap( (person -> person.getID() , Function.identity() ) );
```

Question: So how does the compiler figure out that `Function.identity()` is supposed to return `Function<element of 'people' stream, element of 'people' stream>` stream despite having no inputs?

---

According to the [OpenJDK](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/function/Function.java), the implementation is something like:

```
static <T> Function<T, T> identity()                                                                                                                          
{ 
    return t -> t;    
}
```

An attempt to narrow down my question:
How does `Function.identity()` know what the concrete data type `t` in `t -> t`(btw this is the lambda `Function<T, T>`) is?

Comment: `<T>` _is_ a kind of parameter.

Comment: Type inference is too broad a subject. But this is just how generics work. In the context where you used `Function.identity()`, the compiler inferred type arguments for the method invocation. You could also specify them yourself and be explicit `Function.<Person>identity()` or whatever.

Comment: The compiler figures out the only parameter of `<T>` that would make `toMap` typecheck.

Comment: Thanks for replying so yall are saying type is either inferred or we can specify it. According to [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing),  type is inferred based on `Variable declarations,

Assignments,

Return statements,

Array initializers,

Method or constructor arguments,

Lambda expression bodies,

Conditional expressions, ?:,

Cast expressions,`

Comment: Can I know in this context, which situation are we using to make a type inference here?

Comment: Keep in mind that generics only exist at compile-time and are erased at run-time.

Comment: You can read about *poly expressions*, which are expressions that don't specify a generic type in advance, i.e. their type is inferred from the context. The compiler does all this inference work for you, so that you don't have to provide the generic type explicitly i.e. `Function.<Person>identity()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java type inference algorithm is based on the resolution of *constraint formulas* on *inference variables*. It is described in detail in [Chapter 18 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-18.html). It's a bit involved.

Informally, for the example above the reasoning would go roughly as follows:

We have an invocation of `Function.<T>identity()`. Because most type parameters are named `T`, and consistently with the JLS, I'll use Greek letters to denote inference variables. So in this initial expression `T :: α`. What constraints do we have on `α`?

Well `identity()` returns an instance of `Function<α,α>` used as argument to `toMap`.

```
static <T,K,U> Collector<T,?,Map<K,U>>  toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, 
   Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper)
```

So now we have the constraints `{α :> T, α <: K}` (where `:>` means supertype of and vice-versa). This now requires us to infer `T` and `K` in this expression, which we'll refer to as `β` and `γ`, so: `{α :> β, α <: γ}`. To avoid getting bogged down in details, let's work through `β` only.

`toMap` then returns a collector as argument to `Stream.collect`, which provides us with another source of constraints:

```
collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)
```

So now we know that `{β :> T}`. But here `T` also needs to be inferred, so it becomes an inference variable, and we have `{β :> δ}`.

This is where it starts unfolding, because the type parameter `T` for method `collect` refers to the parameter `T` in `Stream<T>`. So assuming the stream was defined as `Stream<Person>`, now we have `{δ=Person}` and we can reduce as follows:

- `{β :> δ} => {β :> Person}` (`β` is a supertype of `Person`);
- `{α :> β} => {α :> (β :> Person)} => {α :> Person)}` (`α` is a supertype of `Person`);

So through the process of inference we figured out that the type variable for `Function.identity` needs to be `Person` or a supertype of `Person`. A similar process for `α <: γ` would yield `{α <: Person}` (if the return type is specified). So we have two constraints:

- `α` needs to be `Person` or a supertype of `Person`;
- `α` needs to be `Person` or a subtype of `Person`;

Clearly the only type that satisfies all these constraints is `Person`.